# is there any pool for ThreadingMixIn and ForkingMixIn for SocketServer?

Tags: python, concurrency, asyncsocket, python-multithreading, socketserver

I was trying to make an http proxy using BaseHttpServer which is based on SocketServer
which got 2 asynchronous Mixins (ThreadingMixIn and ForkingMixIn)

the problem with those two that they work on each request (allocate a new thread or fork a new subprocess for each request)

is there a Mixin that utilize a pool of let's say 4 subprocesses and 40 threads in each
so requests get handled by those already created threads ?

because this would be a big performance gain and I guess it would save some resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've started a project that solves this issue

https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/python-PooledProcessMixIn

maybe you want to join me finish the TODOs (clean up after CTRL+C)

Comment: I might need to compare it with eventlet-based servers like  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Spawning/

Comment: this no longer works using py 2.7. I get this error when trying your demo: pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock

Comment: I'm using py 2.7, and my code does not pickle anything

Answer (score 13):

You could use a pool from [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) (in stdlib since Python 3.2):

```
from BaseHTTPServer   import HTTPServer, test
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer     import ThreadingMixIn

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor # pip install futures

class PoolMixIn(ThreadingMixIn):
    def process_request(self, request, client_address):
        self.pool.submit(self.process_request_thread, request, client_address)

def main():
    class PoolHTTPServer(PoolMixIn, HTTPServer):
        pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40)

    test(HandlerClass=SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, ServerClass=PoolHTTPServer)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see the implementation for a threading case is rather trivial.

If you save it to `server.py` then you could run it as:

```
$ python -mserver
```

This command uses upto 40 threads to serve requests on `http://your_host:8000/`.

The main use case of `HTTPServer` is for testing purposes.

Comment: this is similar to using the multiprocessing pool, and this is not the optimal solutions, for example it involves queues and pickles ..etc. please see [my solution](https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/python-PooledProcessMixIn/wiki) features.

Comment: @muayyad: 1. this as well as stdlib classes are for development/testing purposes 2. I can expect that the above works due to its simplicity. I can't say the same about your solution 3. do you have any benchmark?

Comment: @j-f-sebastian: I've used siege to benchmark, it doubles the performance (mine trans Rate: 1530, other mixins about 800)